# How do we make a negative integer out of a string of a negative number and vice-versa?

Tags: matrix, string-manipulation, interactive

Negative numbers are not taken into consideration by mathematica's built-in functions.

```
FromDigits["-2"]
```

Gives me this message:

```
FromDigits::nlst: The expression -2 is not a list of digits or a string of valid digits. >>
```

Also:

```
In[2]:=IntegerString[-2]
```

Gives:

```
Out[2]:="2"
```

I was wondering if someone had some code to do this. I'm currently making a small program in mma which will help me enter matrices manually because it's cumbersome to type in every single ,{} for each row/column. Here's what I had in mind:

```
enterMat[x_, y_] := MatrixForm[ReleaseHold[
    Table[Hold[FromDigits[InputString[]]], {x}, {y}]]]
```

Gives me a series of popups in which I enter the value 1 by 1 pressing enter after each to pass to the next value. It's faster and more comfortable to do it this way since I can use the numpad instead. 
My only problem is that it just doesn't work with negative numbers!

If you have a solution or you know a great way to enter/scan/manipulate matrices, I would like to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: I think `ToString` and `ToExpression` are what you are looking for. As for your matrix-input, you might look at this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/169)

Comment: ... and of course this [questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1228/169) and the corresponding answers might also be of interest...

Comment: A negative integer is not a digit! For a given base *b*, the digits are 0, 1, 2, ..., *b* - 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I decided to use finally, based on the code of Faysal Aberkane in [How to visualize/edit a big matrix as a table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/how-to-visualize-edit-a-big-matrix-as-a-table) and Theo Tiger from [Excel column label from integer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27485/excel-column-label-from-integer)

```
ToExcelCol[n_Integer] := 
 Module[{num, base}, base = Floor[Log[26, 25 (n + 1)]];
  num = n - Total[Power[26, #] & /@ (Range[base] - 1)];
  StringJoin@
   PadLeft[FromCharacterCode /@ (IntegerDigits[num, 26] + 65), base, 
    "A"]]

SetAttributes[GetSymbolName, HoldFirst];
GetSymbolName[symbol_] := ToString@HoldForm@symbol;

SetAttributes[editMatrix, HoldFirst];
Options[editMatrix] = {"MaxFields" -> {10, 5}, 
   "ExcelColumnLabel" -> True};
editMatrix[m_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{maxrows = Min[OptionValue["MaxFields"][[1]], Length[m]], 
    maxcols = Min[OptionValue["MaxFields"][[2]], Length[m[[1]]]], 
    excelColumnLabel = OptionValue["ExcelColumnLabel"]}, 
   Interpretation[
    Panel[DynamicModule[{rowoffset = 0, coloffset = 0}, 
      Grid[{{Style[GetSymbolName[m], Bold]}, {Grid[
          Table[With[{x = i, y = j}, 
            Switch[{i, j}, {0, 0}, Spacer[0], {0, _}, 
             Dynamic[
              If[excelColumnLabel, ToExcelCol[y + coloffset], 
               y + coloffset]], {_, 0}, Dynamic[x + rowoffset], _, 
             InputField[Dynamic[m[[x + rowoffset, y + coloffset]]], 
              FieldSize -> 3]]], {i, 0, maxrows}, {j, 0, maxcols}], 
          Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
         If[Length@m > maxrows, 
          VerticalSlider[
           Dynamic[rowoffset], {Length[m] - maxrows, 0, 1}]]}, {If[
          Length@First@m > maxcols, 
          Slider[Dynamic[coloffset], {0, Length[m[[1]]] - maxcols, 
            1}]]}}]]], m]];
```

[image: a matrix]

Answer (score 2):

This question touches on a lot of things and I am not sure which elements to focus on.  I guess I'll take it in reverse order, as you state that the reason for the question is:

> I'm currently making a small program in mma which will help me enter matrices manually because it's cumbersome to type in every single ,{} for each row/column.

Yes, that is cumbersome, and fortunately it's not what you're supposed to do.  Instead please read: [Entering Tables and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html) and start entering your data that way.

For conversion of strings themselves please see [How do you convert a string containing a number in C scientific notation to a Mathematica number?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/121)  There are a number of methods you might select between depending on the application, such as `StringToDouble`, `Read`, `ReadList`, `ImportString`, and `ParseTable`.  If after reviewing the tutorial above you still have an application for these functions please describe it and I shall make a recommendation.